# Is there any API or way to get article or video about specific word?

Tags: api, video, hyperlink, article

My request may sounds wired but I having some required where user will type any word (in English), eg: "Happiness", I should provide any related articles or videos to the provided word in my site.

My question: is there any API that will help to my requirement? or If there no direct API then, can anyone recommend way to achieve this? kind of idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching inside video is not trivial - the most common approaches at this time are usually AI based.

For example, a video can be analysed with objects, text, places etc identified and a frame by frame set of metadata created.

You can then use this metadata to search for your target and extract or play the relevant frames or sections of the video.

It is possible to do the recognition in real time in live streams also, so you can monitor for certain objects or text etc.

The big cloud providers have cloud based solutions which may meet your needs:

- https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence
- https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/video-indexer

There are also self hosted open source alternatives:

- https://github.com/videoflow/videoflow
- https://openai.com/research/clip

Both video and AI are processing intensive and hit usually translates into cost whether you use a service or host yourself so it worth being aware of this and checking which solutions work best and are also most cost effective for your use case.

Comment: Accepted this answer, as this gives me idea on how to move further.